# MySQL Group Records Into Specific Chunks of Time

Tags: mysql

**Hello,**

I am trying to figure out an efficient way to group records into certain chunks. The records are made up of a count and time, see below example. The count is taken every minute.

```
+----------+---------------+---------------+
| count_id | count_reading | count_time    |
+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 5847348  | 168           | 1358174236000 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 5847347  | 342           | 1358174176000 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 5847346  | 228           | 1358174116000 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 5847345  | 240           | 1358174056000 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 5847344  | 12            | 1358173996000 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 5847343  | 0             | 1358173936000 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 5847342  | 48            | 1358173876000 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 5847341  | 480           | 1358173816000 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 5847340  | 473           | 1358173756000 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 5847339  | 380           | 1358173696000 |
+----------+---------------+---------------+
```

What I would like to achieve is the sum of the count over individual shifts, I have two scenarios that I am stuck on...

- The sum over 12 hour shifts that run from 0700-1900 and 1900-0700.
- The sum over shifts that run 0700-1400, 1400-2200 and 2200-0700.

The result would look something like:

```
+---------------+--------------------------------------------+
| count_reading | count_time                                 |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------+
| 10000         | Between 0700 and now starting on the 13th  |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------+
| 20000         | Between 1900 and 0700 starting on the 12th |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------+
| 50000         | Between 0700 and 1900 starting on the 12th |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------+
| 10000         | Between 1900 and 0700 starting on the 11th |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------+
```

I was working on two queries that would tackle the above problem depending on the scenario. I have searched around for help on this with little luck, if anyone out there is able to help me out it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`group by` can take arbitrary clauses and derived values, e.g (in pseudo-ish code):

```
SELECT SUM(count_reading), TIME(count_time) BETWEEN 7 and 19 AS shift
GROUP BY shift
```

You'll end up with two groups - `shift = 1` for 7-19, and `shift = 0` for 19-7`

Similarly for the 3-way shift, a bit more logic:

```
SELECT sum(count_reading),
    CASE WHEN TIME(count_time) BETWEEN 7 AND 14 THEN 1 ELSE
         WHEN TIME(count_time) BETWEEN 14 and 22 THEN 2
         ELSE 3 END AS shift
GROUP BY shift
```

the actual logic/sql syntax should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: Looking at this I have perhaps not made the question clear enough. Your answer gives me the overall total for each shift. What I am looking for is a total for each individual shift that takes place. Example shift 1 on day 1 = 1000, shift 2 on day 1 = 1300, shift 1 on day 2 = 750 and so on. I will update question to suit.

Comment: you can add an extra layer of grouping, e.g. `group by date(count_time), time(count_time)` to get the per-day business.

Comment: Because the shifts span over two dates, this doesn't seem to work? By the way, thank you for your time.

Comment: true. but like I said - you can group on derived/arbitrary values. some extra logic to figure out which date a shift belongs to, etc...

Comment: I have the same problem (shifts running from 21:30), to get the days right i use `DATEADD` to add 180 minutes to the date before grouping. Since the shift starting 21:30 technically belongs to the day after.